# Combine multiple columns of text of multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> I want to combine multiple columns of text from multiple row groups. I
> know that the join joins into a single cell but it doesn't read by
> product. I want a single cell to have the information for that product
> in different brands and continents by the plan.
> For example: Within the laptop product what are the brands and
> continents in plan 1, in plan 2 , 3 and so on?

```
df['all'] = df[['product', 'brand', ...]].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
```

> Here the dataframe:

```
product     brand     continent    plan
laptop         lg       n_am         P1
laptop    samsung       n_am         P1
laptop      apple         eu         P3
tv             lg         eu         P3
tv        samsung         eu         P2
tv          apple       n_am         P2
tv        samsung       n_am         P1
cellphone      lg         eu         P3
cellphone   apple       n_am         P2
cellphone   apple         eu         P1
```

> Expected dataframe:

```
product     brand     continent    plan   all
laptop         lg       n_am         P1   product: laptop; plan: P1; brand: lg-samsung; continent: n_am
laptop    samsung       n_am         P1   product: laptop; plan: P1; brand: lg-samsung; continent: n_am
laptop      apple         eu         P3   product: laptop; plan: P3; brand: apple; continent: eu
tv             lg         eu         P3   product: tv;   plan: P3; brand: lg; continent: eu
tv        samsung         eu         P2   product: tv;   plan: P2; brand: samsung-apple; continent: n_am-eu
tv          apple       n_am         P2   product: tv;   plan: P2; brand: samsung-apple; continent: n_am-eu
tv        samsung       n_am         P1   product: tv;   plan: P1; brand: samsung; continent: n_am
cellphone      lg         eu         P3   product: cellphone; plan: P3; brand: lg; continent: eu
cellphone   apple       n_am         P2   product: cellphone; plan: P2; brand: apple; continent: n_am
cellphone   apple         eu         P1   product: cellphone; plan: P1; brand: apple; continent: eu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` with `sort=False` and `Series.unique`. After that join back and use list comprehension to construct string out of dict and assign to `all` column

```
l1 = (df[['product','plan']].join(df.groupby(['product', 'plan'], sort=False)
                                    .transform(lambda x: '-'.join(x.unique()))).to_dict('records'))
df['all'] = [';'.join(k+':'+v for k, v in x.items()) for x in l1]

Out[528]:
     product    brand continent plan                                                       all
0     laptop       lg      n_am   P1    product:laptop;plan:P1;brand:lg-samsung;continent:n_am
1     laptop  samsung      n_am   P1    product:laptop;plan:P1;brand:lg-samsung;continent:n_am
2     laptop    apple        eu   P3           product:laptop;plan:P3;brand:apple;continent:eu
3         tv       lg        eu   P3                  product:tv;plan:P3;brand:lg;continent:eu
4         tv  samsung        eu   P2  product:tv;plan:P2;brand:samsung-apple;continent:eu-n_am
5         tv    apple      n_am   P2  product:tv;plan:P2;brand:samsung-apple;continent:eu-n_am
6         tv  samsung      n_am   P1           product:tv;plan:P1;brand:samsung;continent:n_am
7  cellphone       lg        eu   P3           product:cellphone;plan:P3;brand:lg;continent:eu
8  cellphone    apple      n_am   P2      product:cellphone;plan:P2;brand:apple;continent:n_am
9  cellphone    apple        eu   P1        product:cellphone;plan:P1;brand:apple;continent:eu
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the required code:

```
#Grouping by the product and plan and then aggregating unique values by placing a hyphen(-) in between. 
df_dict = df.groupby(['product','plan'])[['brand','continent']]\
            .agg(lambda x: "-".join(set(x))).reset_index()

#Merging the above dataframe with the original dataframe to get the values we need
final_df = pd.merge(df.drop(['brand','continent'],axis=1),\
                    df_dict, on=['product','plan'], how='left')

#Finally aggregating all columns by joining the various "column- value" pairs with "; "
final_df['all'] = final_df.apply(lambda x: '; '.join([(i+":"+j) for i, j in x.to_dict().items()]), axis=1)
```

The output is like this:

```
     product plan          brand continent                                                all
0     laptop   P1     samsung-lg      n_am  product:laptop; plan:P1; brand:samsung-lg; con...
1     laptop   P1     samsung-lg      n_am  product:laptop; plan:P1; brand:samsung-lg; con...
2     laptop   P3          apple        eu  product:laptop; plan:P3; brand:apple; continen...
3         tv   P3             lg        eu        product:tv; plan:P3; brand:lg; continent:eu
4         tv   P2  samsung-apple   eu-n_am  product:tv; plan:P2; brand:samsung-apple; cont...
5         tv   P2  samsung-apple   eu-n_am  product:tv; plan:P2; brand:samsung-apple; cont...
6         tv   P1        samsung      n_am  product:tv; plan:P1; brand:samsung; continent:...
7  cellphone   P3             lg        eu  product:cellphone; plan:P3; brand:lg; continen...
8  cellphone   P2          apple      n_am  product:cellphone; plan:P2; brand:apple; conti...
9  cellphone   P1          apple        eu  product:cellphone; plan:P1; brand:apple; conti...
```

PS: There are chances that some of the things that I did could've been done by an inbuilt pandas function. But this code gives you the functionality to tweak at any level.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply dict on `axis=1`

```py
df['all']=df.apply(dict, axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     product    brand continent plan                                                all
0     laptop       lg      n_am   P1  {'product': 'laptop', 'brand': 'lg', 'continen...
1     laptop  samsung      n_am   P1  {'product': 'laptop', 'brand': 'samsung', 'con...
2     laptop    apple        eu   P3  {'product': 'laptop', 'brand': 'apple', 'conti...
3         tv       lg        eu   P3  {'product': 'tv', 'brand': 'lg', 'continent': ...
4         tv  samsung        eu   P2  {'product': 'tv', 'brand': 'samsung', 'contine...
5         tv    apple      n_am   P2  {'product': 'tv', 'brand': 'apple', 'continent...
6         tv  samsung      n_am   P1  {'product': 'tv', 'brand': 'samsung', 'contine...
7  cellphone       lg        eu   P3  {'product': 'cellphone', 'brand': 'lg', 'conti...
8  cellphone    apple      n_am   P2  {'product': 'cellphone', 'brand': 'apple', 'co...
9  cellphone    apple        eu   P1  {'product': 'cellphone', 'brand': 'apple', 'co...
```

And since, your expected output just has the strings not the dictionaries, if that's what you want, you can just convert to string and discard the first and the last values, after converting to dict.

```py
df['all']=df.apply(lambda x:'; '.join(f'{col}: {x[col]}' for col in x.index), axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     product    brand continent plan                                                all
0     laptop       lg      n_am   P1  product: laptop; brand: lg; continent: n_am; p...
1     laptop  samsung      n_am   P1  product: laptop; brand: samsung; continent: n_...
2     laptop    apple        eu   P3  product: laptop; brand: apple; continent: eu; ...
3         tv       lg        eu   P3  product: tv; brand: lg; continent: eu; plan: P...
4         tv  samsung        eu   P2  product: tv; brand: samsung; continent: eu; pl...
5         tv    apple      n_am   P2  product: tv; brand: apple; continent: n_am; pl...
6         tv  samsung      n_am   P1  product: tv; brand: samsung; continent: n_am; ...
7  cellphone       lg        eu   P3  product: cellphone; brand: lg; continent: eu; ...
8  cellphone    apple      n_am   P2  product: cellphone; brand: apple; continent: n...
9  cellphone    apple        eu   P1  product: cellphone; brand: apple; continent: e...
```

Comment: This answer is wrong!! It does not consider the merging case when the plan is same!!

Comment: On a side note, @Don'tAccept can you please give the code for creating this dataframe?

Comment: @paradocslover You can use `pd.read_clipboard()` after copying the df.

Comment: Just copy the dataframe and call `pd.read_clipboard()` @ paradocslover

Comment: Ohhh god!!!! YOU ARE AWESOME @Ch3steR I didn't know this. It worked like magic!!!

Comment: @Don'tAccept Your output doesn't match OP's

Comment: 1st value in `all` column of OP' `product: laptop; plan: P1; brand: lg-samsung; continent: n_am`. Column `brand` should contain all brands with same plan.

Comment: @Ch3steR, yeah I got it, thanks for pointing out .and another issue is obviously the order of the values, since expected value is in string, the order matters. I'll update the answer after fixing them.